# Choice of design pattern for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

Okay I'm in front of a little internal debate. I'm trying to decide what design pattern I should use for my ASP.NET webshop application.I've been searching for a few and these are the ones i find most interesting

- MVC
- MVP
- MVVM

So I'm trying to decide which one to pick. Therefor this question. 
What are the pro's and contra's. Which one is more advisable for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with ASP.NET MVC.

Pros:

1. gives all the goodness associated with [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns),
   e.g. unit-testing is easy
2. MVVM can be used with MVC
3. good community support and examples

MVP has it's benefits, but doesn't beat 1 and 2, and certainly doesn't come anywhere near 3.

Possible cons

1. your team is already highly skilled with another pattern/architecture
2. You don’t need decoupling or therefore the associated complexity

However, MVC isn't particularly difficult so I wouldn't use that as a reason to ignore it. Also, only the most basic application doesn't need decoupling so con 2 probably doesn't apply for the vast majority of cases.